# how set errors from laravel in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to retrieve errors from Laravel in Vue, but i get this error message in my console "Cannot set property 'errors' of undefined".
I have tried different approaches like direct assignment of errors and the $set() of vue to set error message to the error object of my data function, but it is still in vain.

This is my code

```
 export default{

  data(){
    return{
        form: {},
        errors:{}
    }
 },
 methods:{
      async onSave() {
        await Api().post('/stocks/store',this.form)
        .then()
        .catch(function (error) {
           if(error.response && error.response.status == 422) {
              let errors = error.response.data.errors;
              // this.$set(this.$data.errors,'errors',errors)
              console.log(errors);
              this.errors = errors;
           }
        });  
  }
}
```

**This is how the error message from my console**

[image]

**This is the error message from laravel**

[image]

h**ow do set this.errors with error message from laravel**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the error, it says

`Cannot set property 'errors' of undefined`

So the problem is you are trying to set a property of an undefined object, in this case: `this`, your Vue component.

An easy and convenient way to solve this problem is to use arrow function instead of a regular function in your `Promise.catch()` callback. To put simply, a regular function expression has his own `this` context, where arrow function does not.

Here is a sample of code that should help you understand better:

```js
        new Promise().then()
        .catch((error) => {
           if(error.response && error.response.status == 422) {
              this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
           }
        });
```

To learn more about arrow function and [the binding of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Description)